# Spacy pattern matching rule formation

Tags: nlp, spacy

In Spacy pattern matching, how do I write  a SINGLE pattern matching rule that can be triggered by the following patterns:

```
"red", apple"   # ie, the rule must trigger when the input sentence contains "red apple"
"large", "white", "building" # ie, the rule must trigger when the input sentence contains "large white building"
["lamp", "light", "fan"] # ie, the rule must trigger when the input sentence contains a token "light"
```

In the above, each part does not have same number of tokens, and each such part may be more than one token long (so I cannot use the Spacy operator "IN" to combine all these parts)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a single Token Matcher pattern to do that.

But you can assign multiple patterns the same label so there's no reason to do that. If you want to be more specific than labels you can also [add IDs to patterns](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-ent-ids).

Here's how you would make one label with your patterns:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")

patterns = [{"label": "SOMETHING", "pattern": "red apple"},
            {"label": "SOMETHING", "pattern": "large white building"},
            {"label": "SOMETHING", "pattern": "lamp"},
            {"label": "SOMETHING", "pattern": "light"},
            {"label": "SOMETHING", "pattern": "fan"}
            ]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

text = "I saw a red apple under a lamp in the large white building"

for ent in nlp(text).ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent, sep="\t")
```

I used the EntityRuler here, but if you want to use the PhraseMatcher to use the `on_match` functionality you can just do something like `matcher.add("SOMETHING", pattern, myfunc)`.